# JSON dictionaries(?) into Python (Oanda API)

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I am currently trying to integrate a .json file into python, which includes currency instrument information from a data provider.  My intentions are to be able to call list items, to be compared against each other (if candles[0] < candles[1]:, etc).

The .json file looks like this:

```
{
        "instrument" : "EUR_USD",
        "granularity" : "D",
        "candles" : [
                {
                        "time" : "2014-02-17T22:00:00Z",
                        "openMid" : 1.259445,
                        "highMid" : 1.259955,
                        "lowMid" : 1.251825,
                        "closeMid" : 1.257955,
                        "volume" : 61184,
                        "complete" : true
                },
                {
                        "time" : "2014-02-18T22:00:00Z",
                        "openMid" : 1.257975,
                        "highMid" : 1.259955,
                        "lowMid" : 1.251825,
                        "closeMid" : 1.252945,
                        "volume" : 67528,
                        "complete" : false
                }
        ]
}
```

The python reader looks like this thus far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json

with open('EURUSD.json', 'r') as eurusd_data:
    data = json.load(eurusd_data)

data_string = json.dumps(data)
print data_string
```

What do I need to do in order to compare candle dictionary variables?  For instance, candles[0] (with "volume" : 61184 variable), vs candles[1] (with "volume" : 67528 variable).  I feel like there's something very simple I am missing here.
Also, if anyone is curious, I am receiving this data from Oanda's API (which is now free)

Comment: I rather use pyoanda (https://github.com/toloco/pyoanda)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `json.load` call gives you a dictionary with the exact structure of the JSON document you pasted (JSON documents are either JSON objects, which parse as dicts (as in your example), or JSON arrays, which parse as lists).

All you need to do is to compare `data["candles"][0]["volume"]` and `data["candles"][1]["volume"]` to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks Max, that seems to have done the trick!  I knew it was something simple I was not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

`sorted(data[candles], key=lambda candle:candle[volume])` gives you the candles sorted by volume in ascending order.

If you just want to order it and keep it in the data dictionary you just have to overwrite the old list of candles with the new one.

```
sorted_candles = sorted(data[candles], key=lambda candle:candle[volume])
data[candles] = sorted_candles
```